Contacts are showing only as siri found in app
I am using 14 pro max.
My contacts are disappearing.
When I search in contacts it shows as “siri found in app”.
When i receive call/message/wattsapp it only shows number.
Many times i upgraded ios..but same is happening
And some of the contacts are totally deleted.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you make an edit to let us know what device / os version and if you have any contact sync app or setting enabled? A screen snippet of what you see where “it only shows” also can be helpful if personal data is redacted.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yeah sure,i have written clearly that some of the contacts randomly moving to “siri found in apps”.And when i receive call/message/wattsapp,it only shows number instead of contact name.and few of the contacts are totally deleted.
